# addField() does not properly ensure table?

Tags: views, 9

When I create a view with a table display, I configure the table columns to be sortable and set *Dinstinct* to avoid duplicates. I get the following SQL error.

> General error: 3065 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'XYZ' which is not in SELECT list

A proposed solution from [this issue on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3195178) is to add a custom filter which iterates through all the fields set as sortable and add them to the query. The query method of my custom filter plugin looks like this.

```php
public function query() {
  // Force View to DISTINCT (because multiple matches makes duplicate
  // query results), and ensure all fields in DISTINCT exist in query to avoid
  // SQL error "ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list": Table column click
  // to sort (and its default order) adds an additional field too late in the
  // game, so we preemptively add all these fields to the query to anticipate
  // it.
  $this->query->distinct = TRUE;

  // Fields the table sorting plugin might use which might not be in the query.
  $sortable_fields = array_keys(array_filter($this->view->getDisplay()->getOption('style')['options']['info'], function ($item) {
    return $item['sortable'] ?? FALSE;
  }));

  // Get field table meta and add to query:
  foreach ($sortable_fields as $field_name) {
    $field = $this->view->field[$field_name] ?? NULL;
    if ($field) {
      $this->query->addField($field->table, $field->realField);
    }
  }
}
```

This works when the fields/columns are stored in the base table, but when a field that comes from a joined table is used, this fails. The SQL error in this case is the following.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'politician.first_name' in 'field list'

When I look at the query which is shown with the error, I see that the *politican* table is joined but with *politician_candidacies_mandates* as alias. I find the whole query somehow confusing, but the base table of the view is *sidejob*.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "expression" 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT 
"sidejob"."id" AS "id", "politician"."first_name" AS "politician_first_name", "politician"."last_name" AS "politician_last_name", "politician"."party" AS "politician_party", "sidejob"."job_title" AS "sidejob_job_title", "sidejob"."job_title_extra" AS "sidejob_job_title_extra", "sidejob_organization"."name" AS "sidejob_organization_name", "sidejob"."category" AS "sidejob_category", "sidejob"."interval" AS "sidejob_interval", "sidejob"."income_level" AS "sidejob_income_level", "sidejob"."created" AS "sidejob_created", "sidejob"."changed" AS "sidejob_changed", "sidejob"."data_change_date" AS "sidejob_data_change_date", "candidacies_mandates_sidejob__mandates"."id" AS "candidacies_mandates_sidejob__mandates_id", "politician_candidacies_mandates"."id" AS "politician_candidacies_mandates_id", "sidejob_organization_sidejob"."id" AS "sidejob_organization_sidejob_id", 1 AS "expression" FROM {sidejob} "sidejob" 

LEFT JOIN {sidejob__mandates} "sidejob__mandates" ON sidejob.id = sidejob__mandates.entity_id AND sidejob__mandates.deleted = :views_join_condition_0 

LEFT JOIN {candidacies_mandates} "candidacies_mandates_sidejob__mandates" ON sidejob__mandates.mandates_target_id = candidacies_mandates_sidejob__mandates.id 

LEFT JOIN {politician} "politician_candidacies_mandates" ON candidacies_mandates_sidejob__mandates.politician = politician_candidacies_mandates.id 

LEFT JOIN {sidejob_organization} "sidejob_organization_sidejob" ON sidejob.sidejob_organization = sidejob_organization_sidejob.id
) "subquery"
```

When I dig into `addField()` and `ensureTable()`, I don't understand how I could assure the correct relation is used. Maybe the whole solution is not a solution.

Any hint and idea is highly appreciated.